# How to compare two different images using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

We have images stored in static files in `wwwroot` and we want to compare the uploaded images to the images stored there.

We want to compare pictures of humans not objects.

So what should we do?

Answer (score 1):

The go-to and easy to use image-processing library is OpenCV.
The OpenCV library was built using C and C++ programming languages. So, to be able to use OpenCV using C#, you need to use a wrapper written using C#, to communicate with the OpenCV library and all its underlying APIs.

The most popular wrapper is [Emgu CV](https://emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation).